# Python Selenium is not opening the link

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots, geckodriver

Python Selenium is opening a tab but not the link as shown in the given image

[image: It is the code of my simple program]

The issue is that when I run it in Linux, it does not open the link as shown in this image

[image: Here is the image when the program run]
terminal:- [here you go](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwvsM.png)

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try below solution :

```
   from selenium import webdriver
    while True:
        driver =  webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="/usr/local/bin/geckodriver")
        driver.get("http://google.com/")
        driver.quit()
```

Comment: It's Linux not Windows no exe sir

Comment: move your geckodriver to /usr/local/bin/ folder and also make executable permission to geckodriver executable file using chmod command

Comment: its not required for you  remove that

Comment: I will try it today

Comment: what issue are you facing

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: newSession

Comment: Upgrade to the latest versions of geckodriver/selenium

Comment: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/testing/geckodriver/Support.html

Comment: Can you help I can't understand that plz mate

Comment: Can you explain that for me plz

Comment: if you are online come let me know